# adding value to SubElement in ElementTree (Python)

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am looking for supported format in python for passing value of an element as a text value to sub-element. For example i have the below url that i setup as global as it is referenced in many places.

```
global appurl
appurl = 'http://%s/adminapi/application' % ipaddr
```

Now I need to achieve an XML format of this type in Python:

```
<application name="TEST">
            <refURL>http://<ipaddr>/adminapi/application/TEST</refURL>
</application>
```

In python i wrote something of this sort

```
application_e = etree.SubElement(doc,'application', name='TEST')
    refURL_e = etree.SubElement(application_e,'refURL')
    Application = "TEST"
    ApplicationURL = "appurl/%s" % Application
    refURL_e.text = ApplicationURL
```

How do i append {value of Application} i.e. TEST to appurl that i defined globally and assign it as a value to refURL which is sub-element of application.

Comment: Unrelated, but it is recommended to use the newer syntax for format strings: `ApplicationURL = "{}/{}".format(appurl, Application)`

Comment: This format works if i wanted appurl/Application as output. How do i get the values of appurl and Application in similar format. i.e. i need output as http://<ipaddr>/adminapi/application/TEST

Answer (score 0):

ApplicationURL = "{}/{}".format(appurl, Application) worked for me. I just had to declare appurl as global parameter.